# How do i play sound in my C++ Windows Game?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, codeblocks, playsound

Windows 7 Ultimate 64Bit, I am using CodeBlocks 16.01. I am working on my OpenGL college project, I'm trying to add a gun sound effect when the player shoots using the 'spacebar' key.

The sound only works when i create a console project or empty project and the sound plays just fine, I am aware of the library "winmm.lib" that i have to link, and it works just fine as a CONSOLE PROJECT, here is the code for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PlaySound("shotgun.wav",NULL,SND_SYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem begins when i now use this code in my Glut Project, what happens is instead of playing "shotgun.wav" it plays one of the windows system sounds called "Default Beep", When the shooting button "spacebar" is pressed. The game was freezing a few seconds until the sound has completed, however i fixed this issue by replacing thw above line with this one :

```
PlaySound(TEXT("shotgun.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

It doesn't freeze anymore, But Still, It continues to play that Windows System sound instead of the shotgun.wav. The .wav file is IN the project, i'm pretty sure it's in the right place. here is the sample for shoot code from my Glut project (i only copied the relevant piece of code) :

```
void Keys(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
key = tolower(key); //Just in case CAPS LOCK is ON.

    if(key==27)
        exit(0); //Escape key, Exit the game

    switch(key){ 
    case ' ':  //SPACE BAR

            /* some code here */

            PlaySound(TEXT("shotgun.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        break; //.....Code continues to the next case....
```

To force the gun sound effect, i had to go to Windows Sound settings and "Change System sounds", lol yep i actually had to replace "Default Beep" with my "Shotgun.wav", i then returned to the game and compiled, and wala ! It was working. BUT of course this is NOT what i want, cause obviously this will only work on my PC and we don't want that.

Comment: You could use OpenAL or the SDL to play sounds, it's better because it's OS independent.

Comment: Double check that the shotgun.wav file is in the folder where your application is executing.  It may not be finding the file.

Comment: That was my default guess too: Codeblocks probably builds the executable to a temporary directory and runs from there, without copying resources alongside?

Comment: @Dan the file is in the right folder

Comment: @Nasso, well could you please show me how.

Comment: @Ndum'ndayiMhlongo I'm sure there is a lot of tutorial on internet, and using lower level API such as OpenAL is easier for debugging and you can easily play 3D sounds. Also, you can control the reading of the file yourself.

Comment: Test the returned value. If false, Use GetLastError to find the error code. In Visual Studio, paste the error code in Tools | Error lookup (if I correctly recall).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full file path. Use double slash `\\` in between. For example:

```
sndPlaySound("D:\\New folder(2)\\poiuy\\sound.wav",SND_ASYNC|SND_LOOP);
```